# How can I remove the cameraOverlayView from the editing screen of UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios

I've set a custom view as the `cameraOverlayView` of an `UIImagePickerController`
and enabled editing mode on it.

Now when it switches to editing mode the overlay view is still there.
How can I remove it from the editing view?

I haven't found anything related to this in the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried *view.removeFromSuperview*?

I take it you've implemented the delegate function

```
optional func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
```

and this happens before that function gets called.

Can your custom view detect that its parent has changed and remove itself?

Comment: If I had known when to call it, I would have already tried it.  

The problem is that I don't know when the image picker switches to editing mode, `UIImagePickerController` doesn't have a delegate method for that.

Comment: That's reasonable.